# Constructing an object using a type of a generic?

Tags: generics, typescript

I'm working with a public RESTful API that returns objects that have fields of URLs that point to more info. I'd like to wrap these fields in an object that indicates what they point to so I created an object like so:

```
class APIResource<T> {
    url: string;
}
```

Where `T` describes what the `url` should return. `T` isn't actually even used by the object as far as typescript is concerned but it helps me know what I should expect. I'm working with Angular2 but please note that what I'm trying to do is not Angular specific. I have an API class where I can request a URL and provide a type to convert it to:

```
class Person {
  name: string;
  age: number;

  constructor(obj: any) {
    // all Constructable<T> classes will
    // have a constructor that looks
    // exactly like this
    Object.assign(this, obj);
  }

  print() {
    console.log(this.name + ' is ' + this.age);
  }
}

interface Constructable<T> {
  new (obj: any): T;
}

public get<T>(url: string, type: Constructable<T>): Observable<T> {
  return this.http.get(url).map(result => {
    return new type(result.json());
  });
}
```

Basically, I make an ajax request to get json from the API, I pass it through the constructor of my type and return the object. It would be used like this:

```
var person: Person;
api.get('/person/1/', Person).subscribe(p => person = p);
```

This works if I have the constructor to pass in, but what I'd like to do is write up a `getResource<T>(resource: APIResource<T>): Observable<T>` function so I could do something like this:

```
var res: APIResource<Person> = { url: '/person/1/' };
var person: Person;
api.getResource(res).subscribe(p => person = p);
```

But so far nothing has worked. Right now I can't get the type `T` out of `APIResource` to use my current method. I've tried modifying APIResource:

```
class APIResource<T> {
  url: string;

  getType(): T {
    return T;
  }
}
```

Or

```
class APIResource<T extends Constructable<T>> {
  url: string;

  fetch(): T {
    // just a test to see if tsc complains
    // which it does with "cannot find name T"
    var obj: any = {};
    return new T(obj);
  }
}
```

But neither of them work. I know the type information is gone once it's javascript. Instead of the type moving around, I think I'd be able to work with moving around the constructor but I don't think I can do that with generics.

Is there anyway to make this work with generics?

I'm using typescript 1.8.7

Comment: The TypeScript FAQ section on Generics has three questions, each of which you ask here :) https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#generics

Comment: Ever get a good answer on this?

Comment: @Shane my answer from 2016 is a good answer on this lol. Did you try it?

Comment: @rob3c I ended up going with something kinda similar. I feel like having to pass in the object rather than have it be inferred is not all that 'good' per se, but not your fault.

Comment: @Shane Not sure what "having to pass in the object rather than have it be inferred" means. This way passes the type, not an instance. Yes TS isn't ideal here, but don't you have to parametrize the type one way or another with generics? TS doesn't let you use generic params within functions like some languages - info is gone at runtime. This way shifts from passing it as generic param to passing it directly. It's still passed only once, so no less efficient than in the question. In fact no brackets are required when `Person` is passed directly, so one could argue it's 2 chars more efficient :-)

Answer (score 3):

Here's a way to do it in TypeScript with generics to retain strong typing:

```js
interface Constructable<T> {
    ctor: new (...args) => T;
    url: string;
}

class APIResource<T> implements Constructable<T> {
    constructor(
        public ctor: new (...args) => T,
        public url: string
    ) {}
}

class Person {
    name: string;
    age: number;

    constructor(obj: any) {
        //Object.assign(this, obj); // requires ES6
        for (var key in obj) this[key] = obj[key];
    }

    print() {
        console.log(`${this.name} is ${this.age}`);
    }
}

function getResource<T>(apiResource: APIResource<T>): T {
    console.log(`resource url: "${apiResource.url}"`);

    // pretend this came back from an ajax request    
    let obj: any = { name: 'Arthur', age: 42 };
    console.log(`obj instanceof Person? ${obj instanceof Person}`); // false

    return new apiResource.ctor(obj);
}

const res = new APIResource(Person, '/person/1/');
let person = getResource(res);

console.log(`person instanceof Person? ${person instanceof Person}`); // true
person.print();
```

[image: strong typing is preserved to enable intellisense]

I simplified the code so that it'll run in a single, self-contained TypeScript file to show the idea without requiring the Angular 2 and rxjs dependencies. However, extending it to an http call in Angular 2 is straight-forward (split into multiple maps for clarity):

```
getResource<T>(apiResource: APIResource<T>): Observable<T> {
    return this.http.get(apiResource.url)
        .map(result => result.json())
        .map(obj => new apiResource.ctor(obj));
}
```

And then you can consume the strongly-typed result via `subscribe`, as usual.